# Problem with PublishProfile parameter for MSBuild on TFS Server

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

On a TFS 2018 server, I'm trying to set up automated build and deploy. 
The build is running fine, but I can't seem to get the publish/deploy to work (tried several methods). The application is a ASP.Net MVC website.

One approach is to use MSbuild parameters to choose a PublishProfile, but I get an error stating that the profile does not exists. Can't figure out why, cause to my understanding it does exist.

Anyone who'd made this work? Or have an easier approach for automated build and publish from TFS 2018 to a folder?

Comment: Is the profile also checked into source control? Do you see it when browsing the code via the Web UI?

Comment: yes, it is. I just verified that it's available also through the Web UI

Comment: And when you connect to the agent and look into that file system path? (assuming it is a local build agent machine)

Comment: Yes, everything seems to be ok. I do however just found a workaround. Posting update

Comment: If you can skip Publish Profile concept/task, better use Publish Build Artifacts task and provide Artifact Type as File Share on creating a shared path [accessible for all]. Later Deployment can be pointed from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the MSBuild arguments from

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile="MyProfile"
```

to

```
/p:OutDir="\\path-to-some-folder"
```

proved to be a workaround that worked for me. Now I can copy files from the output folder to my website(s).